# How do I check if a discord.js bot is inside the same voice channel as the member?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

**The problem:**
I can't check if the dscord.js bot that I programmed is in the same voice channel as a member that is trying to command it. I need a function like: `if (client.member.voice.channel==true)`. And then if the "IF" statement is true the bot will do the command, and if it is not the bot will apologize and say that you need to be in the same channel as the bot.

**The code I am using:**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Music Bot'));



app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Web is ready!`));



const Discord = require('discord.js');


const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');

const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

const ffmpeg = require('ffmpeg-static');

const client = new Discord.Client()
//=========================================


client.once( 'ready', () => {


console.log('Bot is ready!')

client.user.setActivity(`Use +play or +leave!`, { type: "LISTENING" }).catch(console.error)

});



client.on('message', async msg => {


const args = msg.content.trim().split(/ +/g);



if(msg.content.startsWith('+play'))
{
const voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel;

let videoName = msg.content.slice(5).trim()
 
        if (!voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to play music!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(msg.client.user);
        
        if (!videoName) return msg.channel.send('You need to type the song name!');
 
        const validURL = (str) =>{
            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if(!regex.test(str)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
 
        if(validURL(args[0])){
 
            const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            const stream  = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
 
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
                msg.channel.send('Leaving channe!');
            });
 
            await msg.reply(`Now Playing ***Your Link!***`)
 
            return
        }
 
        
        const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
 
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
 
            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
 
        }
 
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
 
        if(video){
            const stream  = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });
 
            await msg.reply(`Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        } else {
            msg.channel.send('No results found');
        }

}

if(msg.content.startsWith('+leave'))
{

 const voiceChannel = msg.member.voice.channel;
 
        if(!voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send("You need to be in a voice channel to stop the music!");
        await voiceChannel.leave();
        await msg.channel.send(`Leaving **${voiceChannel.name}**!`)




}









});


client.login(process.env.Token)
```

**What I need:**

A function that checks if the bot is already in another voice channel, works similar to the code above, in "The problem".

THANKS

Comment: This has been asked and answered on the discord.js subreddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/Discordjs/comments/mouxsj/check_if_the_bot_is_online_in_a_voice_channel/

Comment: "*it all didn't work*" isn't a helpful problem statement. Please edit your question to include your code as a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), along with an explanation of where *specifically* you're getting stuck. Include the full text of pertinent error messages as text in the body of your question. Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `client` has a [`voice`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=voice) property that returns a `ClientVoiceManager`. [`voice.connections`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/v12/class/ClientVoiceManager?scrollTo=connections) returns a collection of `VoiceConnection`s, so it has a `size` property.

It means you can check if `client.voice.connections.size` is greater than 0. If it is, the bot is in a voice channel.

In discord.js v13 and v14, the `ClientVoiceManager` no longer has a `connections` property, however, you can use [`client.voice.adapters`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ClientVoiceManager?scrollTo=adapters). In this case, you can check `client.voice.adapters.size`.

Comment: I want to check if the user is not in the same channel as the bot I tried `if(!client.voice.connections ==  msg.member.voice.channel) return mesg.channel.send(....)` but didn't work

Comment: As I said, `connections` is a collection. I even added links, so you can read the actual documentation. My answer answers your question, it checks if the bot is in a voice channel. If it works, you can accept it. It's probably better to ask a new question with the details in your comment, I'm happy to help there.

Comment: Oh wait it says cannot read the property channel of undefined

Comment: I typed `let voiceBot = client.voice.connections.voice.channel` and did `       
 if(!voiceBot == voiceChannel) return msg.channel.send('TESTED')` but didn't work

Comment: Well, if there are no `connections`, it will be undefined and you can't read any properties of that. It's better to ask a new question though about how to check if the bot is in the same channel as the user. I'll be happy to help there too ;)

Comment: ClientVoiceManager doesn't has `connections` anymore on 14.7.1. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/14.7.1/class/ClientVoiceManager